# Symfony 3 Problems Unrecognized options

Tags: config, symfony

I had this message error 4 hours ago I tried to resolved but I didn't know where is the problem may all files are truly configured?

the message Error:

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
  Unrecognized options "db_driver, firewall_name, user_class" under "fos_user"

config.yml:

```
    #Fos
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Fos\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

AppKernel.php:

```
   <?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Fos\UserBundle\FosUserBundle(),
        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Doctrine or Propel?

Comment: i use Doctrine ORM , still now , i didn't resolve that

Comment: Try this: `# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    translator: ~`

Comment: And create User Entity in your FooBundle.

Comment: yes i have it also ... i have many projects that are work good with those configurations , but this one i don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

**FOSUserBundle** installation:

For Doctrine ORM Entity **`User`** class(You have to create new Class):

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Your `security.yml`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
       FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
       ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
       ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
       fos_userbundle:
           id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
       main:
           pattern: ^/
           form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

           logout:       true
           anonymous:    true

    access_control:
       - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
       - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Config `config.yml`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Here `AppBundle\Entity\User` class that you created new class

Add to Routing `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Update your database schema:
`$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`